# Inserting indexed array into an database with PHP and MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get an indexed array's values inserted into a SQL database with MySQLi and PHP but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pword","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Unable to connect to MySQL! ". mysqli_connect_error();
   exit();
}

$sqli = "INSERT INTO path_info (path_name,operating_frequency,pi_description,pi_note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $con->prepare($sqli);
$stmt->bindParam("ssss",$csv[0],$csv[1],$csv[2],$csv[3]);
$status = $stmt->execute();
if (!$status) {
    echo "Error ".$stmt->errorCode()."\nMessage ".implode($stmt->errorInfo())."\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: remove ; from insert query

Comment: Show the value of $csv[0]. and what is value of $status after executing the code?

Comment: I removed the ; from the insert, $csv[0] should be a string value. How would I get the value of $status?

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

problem is at `bindParam`

```
$stmt->bindParam(1,$csv[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$csv[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$csv[2]);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$csv[3]);
```

correct format is as above

also use `try-catch`

```
$con= new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=task", 'root', 'root');
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$csv = array('test', 15, 'testing', 'noted');
$sqli = "INSERT INTO path_info (path_name,operating_frequency,pi_description,pi_note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt= $con->prepare($sqli);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$csv[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$csv[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$csv[2]);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$csv[3]);
$status = $stmt->execute(); 
if (!$stmt) {
    echo PDO::errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Still returning empty set

Comment: your connection type is also require to be updated as PDO connection

Comment: Ok, that's added, but it's still not in the db, should I add more of my code to the post?

Comment: refer updated code it working smoothly at my local

Comment: hmm, must be an issue with my array then, thanks for your help.

Comment: DO NOT use try catch. it is useless here

Comment: @YourCommonSense Should I just leave it how I had it before? as far as try catch goes?

Comment: @ZurichinPain the first and foremost thing you have to do is to make your mind **which database API** you are going to use, PDO or mysqli. Your question is tagged with mysqli, your code is a mix between mysqli and PDO and you accepted the answer with PDO.

Comment: @ZurichinPain the way you had it before is even more useless. There should be no try catch nor if (!$status) {. PHP can report errors all by itself, no assistance required.

Comment: I'm going to use whichever one I can get to work.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer, because of try-catch. Never catch exceptions if you don't know how to recover.

Comment: @Dharman removed `try-catch`

Comment: But you added the `if` statement. That's not an improvement. The point is never display the error message! Don't check for errors manually and don't catch the exceptions.

Comment: You use `$stmt` so obviously it is not false. This `if` will never be executed. Such error checking is completely useless, because any call to any of the methods could fail and the rest of the code would never be executed.

Comment: I am printing PDO::errorInfo() not stoping code to be executed

Answer (score 1):

It's bind_param when working with mysqli.
It's bindParam when working with PDO.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pword","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Unable to connect to MySQL! ". mysqli_connect_error();
       exit();
    }

    $sqli = "INSERT INTO path_info (path_name,operating_frequency,pi_description,pi_note) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt= $con->prepare($sqli);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $csv[0],$csv[1],$csv[2],$csv[3]);
    $status = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: check code connection string too

Comment: @RonakDhoot, sorry the connection is that which I used for my local system to test code. Sorry for that.

Comment: it should be PDO connection not mysqli_connect

Comment: It is working fine on my local system.

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)